# Probability of tail event using Kolmogorov's 0-1 law

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

If $X_1,X_2,... $ are independent random variables and $X=\sup_nX_n$ then $P(X<\infty)$ is either 0 or 1.

I think that if we prove the event to be a tail event then the result will follow. But I just don't know how to prove it to be a tail event.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that for each $n$, $\{X<\infty\} = \{\sup_{k\ge n}X_k <\infty\}$.